# Compare volume levels between to mp3/wav files

Tags: java, jsp, audio, mp3, wav

I have two audio recordings that are going to be recorded and saved in mp3 format. The content of the mp3's will be short, only a couple seconds, will be the same audio, but recorded at 2 different volume levels. I would like to use java, or preferably jsp so I can run it on a server, to tell me if there is a difference in volume between these two files. If anyone has any suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it!

Thank you.

Comment: did you end up figuring this out. i have the same issue.  i have two files and i want to compare there volumes

Answer (score 0):

Look at Java Sound API http://www.jsresources.org/faq_audio.html#compare_files

---

```
 Port lineIn;
        FloatControl volCtrl;
        try {
          mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(null);
          lineIn = (Port)mixer.getLine(Port.Info.LINE_IN);
          lineIn.open();
          volCtrl = (FloatControl) lineIn.getControl(

              FloatControl.Type.VOLUME);
// Assuming getControl call succeeds, 
  // we now have a way to detect volume calls
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Failed trying to find LINE_IN"
    + " VOLUME control: exception = " + e);
}
```

Comment: I assume lineIn is the input file? How do I open an mp3 to be used in this context?

Comment: `FloatControl.Type.VOLUME`  is more like the volume control on the stereo.  It affects the overall volume, but tells us nothing about the instantaneous volume (dB, RMS) of the sound signal.

Comment: But using `FloatControl.Type.VOLUME`, can I use it to compare to another audio source?

Comment: Yes but if you are aiming to synchronize the two audio sources to the same level volCntrl can come handy once you figure out the ideal dB and RMS

Comment: Can I just compare two FloatControl objects? FloatControlOne > FloatControlTwo? and how do I assign a wav file to be the input in this situation?

Comment: @Wingdom If the link I gave you wasn't helpful enough here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840611/how-do-i-correctly-use-floatcontrol-with-the-java-sound-api

Comment: I am not looking to adjust the volume level of anything, I just want to open a sound file, wav appears to be easier, and compare it to a second file, and determine which is louder.